# GraphQL API request pass in postman but failed in cypress

Tags: graphql, cypress, web-api-testing

When I try to send a request using postman it will pass with status code 200 but when I run the cypress test it will return an error.

This is a postman image

[image: enter code here]

When I run my cypress test it will return the below error

[image]

Here is my cypress test.

```
it('Sign up', function () {
    cy.readFile("cypress/fixtures/data.json").then((profile) => {
        var OTPQuery = 'mutation { verifyEmailOtp(email: "' + profile.email + '", otp: ' + profile.OTP + '){ message } }'

        cy.log(OTPQuery)
        cy.wait(2000)
        cy.request({
            method: "POST",
            url: "https://api.outsized.site/graphql",
            // failOnStatusCode: false,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
            },
            body: {
                query: OTPQuery
            }

        }).as('rq')
        cy.wait('@rq').then((res) => {
            expect(res.status).to.eq(200)

        });
    })
})
```

Anyone helps me to find out what's the problem here?

Comment: Your postman request doesn't name the field as `query`, but instead just has the string as is. Have you tried just setting the body to `OTPQuery`, without placing it in an object or setting as the value of field `query`?

Comment: @agoff, Yes I have tried but the same error. see test results in screenshots [https://ibb.co/bQtKc64 ] and here are my test screenshots [https://ibb.co/zFBYssm ]